# Сортировка запроса MYSQL

Tags: sql, mysql

Приветствую! У меня такой вопрос: приходит массив id-шек и их нужно вывести в порядке расположения в массиве.

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=45646 OR id=52535 OR id=154876 OR....
```

Нужно, чтобы сортировка была строго по очередности id, как в запросе 45646, 52535, 154876 и т.д. это возможно? А также, подозреваю, что запрос можно как-то изменить (не через OR)? 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

... `WHERE id IN(45646, 52535, 154876) [ORDER BY][1] id ASC`

Ай, тогда сложнее,

```sql
SELECT id, 
  CASE id 
    WHEN 45646 THEN 1 
    WHEN 52535 THEN 2
    WHEN 154876 THEN 3
    ELSE 0
    END
  AS sort 
FROM table
WHERE id IN(45646, 52535, 154876)
ORDER BY sort ASC;
```

Как-то так, поиграйтесь.

Comment: так отсортирует по возрастанию id в таблице, а надо как в запросе...

Comment: все равно сортирует по таблице...т.е. например SELECT * FROM  `releases` 
WHERE id IN ( 2, 1, 3, 7, 4 ) ORDER BY r_id ASC 
выводит 1, 2, 3, 4, 7

Comment: Обновил

Comment: работает, спасибо!