# Сортировка по фиксированному набору значений

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Делаю историю просмотренных страниц, запись идёт в куки - сперва последняя просмотренная, затем позднее и позднее. Пример: `100,50,41,129`

далее берётся эта кука и путём некоторых действий подставляется в запрос, который получается вида

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = 1 AND ( id = 100 OR id = 50 OR id = 41 OR id = 129 )
```

Разумеется, записи сортируются по стандарту ASC, как сделать сортировку по именно этим id в этом же порядке? foreach цикл **не** предлагать, вывожу через `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {...`

Comment: Думаю дубль этого вопроса http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/26515/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-mysql

Comment: Спасибо, не видел

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В MySQL есть специальная опция для этого: `ORDER BY FIELD()`.
Конструкция такая

```
SELECT * FROM [table] ORDER BY FIELD([field_name], [list_of_values_in_order])
```

Т.е. в Вашем случае это работает вот так:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE status = 1 AND ( id = 100 OR id = 50 OR id = 41 OR id = 129 ) 
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 100, 50, 41, 129)
```

---

И еще, я бы поменял

```
(id = 100 OR id = 50 OR id = 41 OR id = 129)
```

на

```
id IN (100, 50, 41, 129)
```